# Eclipse PDE- detecting/linking to method declarations in custom language

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

I recently implemented a small TextEditor-based plugin for handling a custom scripting language in eclipse, and I'd like to be able to jump from function-calls within the code to the function's declaration, just as one could for java methods.

I can implement Hyperlinks and a HyperlinkDetector easily enough, but how would I define a way of detecting function declarations with the project's filespace, so that I can link back to those?

A typical function declaration looks like this (for the curious)-

```
function foo(float x, boolean b) is integer
declare
  integer localVar;
begin
  ... do junk
  return localVar;
end
```

(There's a tutorial on hyperlink creation [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecl-commplgin3/), but this only covers jumping around within the same document.  I'd like to be able to open other files, if needed.)

Comment: This requires you to have a lot of information about where things are. Do you have something like the [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) and indexes that Eclipse JDT uses to manage this sort of information?

Comment: I don't think so at the moment, but the syntax is fairly flat- just global constants, function definitions and 'agent' prototypes (used to represent buildings, creatures, spells, et cetera) that are similar to structs.  So I was hoping I could adapt/extend the existing AST classes for the purpose.